# Detect what page the user came from

Tags: php, authentication

I have a few websites:
- https://ictsupport.ga
- https://auth.ictsupport.ga
- https://account.ictsupport.ga
- https://admin.ictsupport.ga

A user needs to be authenticated on the auth.ictsupport.ga site. After the user has logged in, it needs to be redirected to the protected page where the user came from (ictsupport.ga, account.ictsupport.ga or admin.ictsupport.ga)

How can I do this?

Comment: I think the session variable would make it.

Comment: Like adding a session variable after visiting the page, then redirecting to auth, and reading the session again? Like the idea!

Comment: try this $_SERVER["HTTP_REFERER"]

Comment: HI there, welcome to stackoverflow.  Take a few minutes and read these: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve . You'll have a better chance of getting a quality answer to your question if you follow those guidelines.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On all your pages, (or single index.php) after you have called `session_start()`
set `$_SESSION['lastUrl'] = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']` at the end of the script. so the rest of your script can access the previous url before it is later revalued.

Comment: So I need to place those tags on the admin.ictsupport.ga, account.ictsupport.ga and ictsupport.ga? And then read the session on the auth.ictsupport.ga?

Comment: I'm not sure if your session data will work across subdomains, depends on your setup. If you are with a decent and experienced webhost, your should be able to have it setup. But if you placed this snippet of code on your main php file (I'm not currently aware of your system setup, but I work MVC so index.php is the main file) and place it before the script finishes executing, it should work no problems

Comment: I did something (I’m not sure what...) but sessions are working across subdomains! @Hudson

Comment: In that case, it should work,  the snippet of code I've commented.

Answer (score 0):

Use the `$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']` it will give the last page url whether it is from same application or from a external site.

```
$lastUrl = isset($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']) ? $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'] : '';
```

Comment: 'HTTP_REFERER'
The address of the page (if any) which referred the user agent to the current page. This is set by the user agent. Not all user agents will set this, and some provide the ability to modify HTTP_REFERER as a feature. In short, it cannot really be trusted.

Comment: If you think so then you need manage session for each to achieve this. That is the also an reliable way to fulfill your requirement. If you are using session then you need to store session data in a centralized storage system so you can access this across the servers

Comment: Session seems a better way to do this. Only will work internally though. For an external use, You could use the combination of both our answers. Check for HTTP_Referrer and if empty, use session data. But as i said, sessions are internal.

Comment: well an another way is to go with a no-sql db or centralized cached like redis or memcached. This can be used externally as well.

Comment: Depending on his application, he could also use javascript to track site usage. Google Analytics is a great example of this.

Comment: It always depends on type of application and usage. any way it was a nice discussion on this topic. Came to know several ways to handle a situation like this.

Answer (score 0):

First possibility: You need to make cross-domain authentication.

Second possibility: On first site (account.ictsupport.ga, admin.ictsupport.ga) generate token for user, store it in database and redirect user with token in address (www.finaldestination.com/?token=someTokenizedToken). On you final site, you can lookup associated user with this token and authenticate him as admin or other user. You can make small api point restricted to ip of your finaldestination site for receiving information about user for token. Maybe restrict it to n requests per m time. You can limit lifespan of token for few seconds, because the redirect will be automatic, so it should be more secure.

Comment: What is cross-domain authentication?